# How to interpret forest plot with hazard ratio?

Tags: r, survival

[image]

So this is my forest plot off a dataset found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records)

'Ejection' Fraction clearly has something over the other variables.

I have written:

> `Ejection Fraction` is the only significant variable from cox regression that does improve survival rate probability when it is present (these are all variables with values < 0.05.

Would you say that this is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is misleading. It depends on the directions in which the predictors are defined.

For example, one could have defined "lack of hypertension" as a predictor instead of "hypertension." Then "lack of hypertension" would also be related to improved survival.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for that insight. I'm just learning about this. For this forest plot, specifically, it is the presence of hypertension.